# Getting compiler error when removing typedef in a C++ struct

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

Initially I had the following.

```
struct A: public B
{                 
};

typedef struct A C;
```

Now, I changed that into

```
typedef struct: public B
{                 
} C;
```

and I get a link error for all functions getting

```
fun(C*)
```

as a parameter.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Why not simply say `struct C : public B {};`? Also in C++ structs don't live in separate namespace.

Comment: Removed the C tag. Inheritance is  involved. Therefore the question has nothing to do with C

Comment: What linker error do you get?

Comment: What's the error you get exactly? Also, I compiled your code and it worked fine. See http://ideone.com/rIXwD You'll have to show where you call fun.

Comment: [This](http://www.ideone.com/YyBLX) works for me. So please be clear about what problem you are facing.

Comment: Your second source - the one with the typedef - just seems plain wrong, considering that this is supposed to be C++ not C! (in C++ structs and classes don't have to be qualified by the struct/class-keyword! IMHO: without looking up the spec, I think that's even illegal!) try: `struct C : public B` I'd say that your first example is illegal too due to the typedef! (should be: typedef A C; )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but a couple ideas: You can't forward declare typedefs, so if someone was forward declaring `A` that could cause issues (even if it seems unrelated).

I suspect the real problem is because you're `typedef`ing the struct instead of naming it. Almost certainly this is causing the compiler to give it different linkage (for example it gets different decorated name in each file) and it can't find the appropriate functions.

Finally, since you're using inheritance this must be C++, so you probably shouldn't be using `typedef` for your `struct`s at all.

Comment: The issue was that i am typedefing a struct without naming it on C++. thanks